# pandas combine columns without null keep string values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to combine columns without null and keep string values.

Example data:

```
a,b,c
123.jpg,213.jpg,987.jpg
,159.jpg,
```

There is my code:

```
cols = ['a','b','c']
df['combine_columns'] = df[cols].stack().groupby(level=0),agg(','.join)
print(df)
```

And the result:

```
a,b,c,combine_columns
123.jpg,213.jpg,987.jpg,"123.jpg,213.jpg,987.jpg"
,159.jpg,,159.jpg
```

But I want something like this:

```
a,b,c,combine_columns
123.jpg,213.jpg,987.jpg,""123.jpg","213.jpg","987.jpg""
,159.jpg,,"159.jpg"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` with a list comprehension and [`pandas.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) as filter:

```
df['combine_columns'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join([e for e in x if pd.notna(e)]),
                                 axis=1)
```

output:

```
         a        b        c          combine_columns
0  123.jpg  213.jpg  987.jpg  123.jpg,213.jpg,987.jpg
1      NaN  159.jpg      NaN                  159.jpg
```

Adding extra `"` in the string:

```
df['combine_columns'] = df.apply(lambda x: '"%s"' % ','.join([e for e in x if pd.notna(e)]),
                                 axis=1)
```

output:

```
         a        b        c            combine_columns
0  123.jpg  213.jpg  987.jpg  "123.jpg,213.jpg,987.jpg"
1      NaN  159.jpg      NaN                  "159.jpg"
```

Comment: but how can I keep ""?

Comment: @Teemo not sure that you really need to add `"`, the result **is a string**,  pandas just doesn't show the `"`. But I added a solution